# Silverlight VideoPlayback - How to programmatically set Mode

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

In my Silverlight application I have a `MediaElement` for Video.

I want to be able to change the Mode from `TwoWay` to `OneWay` programaticly.

```
Position="{Binding Position, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Here is the Xaml of the MediaElement

```
            <MediaElement x:Name="media" 
               Source="wildlife.wmv"
               AutoPlay="False"
               Stretch="UniformToFill"
               Position="{Binding Position, Mode=TwoWay}"
               MediaEnded="media_MediaEnded" 
               MediaFailed="media_MediaFailed" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
Binding binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(media, MediaElement.PositionProperty);
binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
```

Comment: When I try this VS error is: Error 'System.Windows.Data.BindingOperations' does not contain a definition for 'GetBinding'

Comment: @IEnumerable, sorry, it is not applicable for silverlight.

Comment: thats ok, thanks for posting, will this work in WPF ?